# oracle sql select query

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by

I am using oracle's SQL Developer. To begin with, I have this table:

```
Name           Null     Type         
-------------- -------- ------------ 
EMPLOYEE_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(6)    
FIRST_NAME              VARCHAR2(20) 
LAST_NAME      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)  
DEPARTMENT_ID           NUMBER(4)
```

I would like for each employee to show his name and the number of colleagues from
his department. This is what I got so far:

```
select first_name, department_id, count(employee_id)
from employees
group by department_id;
```

This generates an error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
```

I would really need some help. I am a total beginner so any suggestion is welcome.

UPDATE: So, for each Employee, I want to show the number of his colleagues from the same department, and his name. I have updated the question.

Comment: [There's nothing wrong with the syntax of your query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7b922/1). Are you sure there's nothing else in the buffer that you're accidentally executing along with it? Also, I'm not sure about SQL developer, but try without the terminating `;`.

Comment: Are you still getting the syntax error, or is the question about the new functionality now?

Comment: It's the same, I need the number of colleagues so that would be the count -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query you posted would not generate the error you indicate

```
SQL> create table employees(
  2    employee_id number primary key,
  3    first_name varchar2(20),
  4    last_name varchar2(25),
  5    department_id number
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> select first_name, department_id, count(employee_id)
  2  from employees
  3  group by first_name, department_id;

no rows selected
```

However, it would also not produce the results that you seem to indicate that you want.  From your description, it appears that you want something like

```
select first_name, 
       last_name, 
       count(*) over (partition by department_id) - 1 num_colleagues_in_department
  from employees
```

Comment: Yes, but I would need the number of his colleagues so that would be -1, where should I insert -1 ?

Comment: @Theo - I'm not sure I understand what -1 represents.  How can a department have -1 employees?  If you are saying that you don't want to count the employee and you only want to count the other employees in the department `count(*) over (partition by department_id) - 1` would be valid

Comment: SO a department has x number of employees. But the employee Y has x-1 number of colleagues, right? We have to exclude him from the count, because I need the number of colleagues for each employee.

Comment: Regardless of if you subtract one or not, you're way better off compared to where you started. over..partition is new to me it indeed simplifies the query!

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.firstname, a.department_id, 
(select count(employee_id) from employees b where b.department_id = a.department_id and b.employee_id <> a.employee_id) as total_in_dept
from employees a
```

this is roughly how I'd do it.  It is a subquery.  http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/subqueries.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, among other ways, using a subquery (as many other answers) or a `LEFT JOIN` like this one;

```
SELECT u.employee_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.department_id,
       COUNT(c.employee_id)-1 colleagues
FROM employees u
LEFT JOIN employees c
  ON u.department_id=c.department_id
GROUP BY u.employee_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.department_id
ORDER BY employee_id
```

A normal `JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` would only return users that actually have at least one colleague, a `LEFT JOIN` returns users even if they don't have a colleague so we can count them.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/26399/2).